# Series 2 Charger Module to Charge 2Cell Li-ion Battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

So for a portable project, I will be using two lithium ion 2200mah 3.7v batteries in series to give me 7.4v. I have two 3.7v Lithium Ion charger found here https://www.adafruit.com/products/1905 .
The question is can I series my charger modules to charge my 2 cell battery?

Comment: If you power them from separate completely isolated USB supplies, yes. If you aren't certain of their isolation, no.  You'd be better getting a proper 2S charger.

Comment: If I don't use module, is there any circuit suggestion to charge 2 cell Li-ion battery?